# String splitting based on Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to split a string which looks like this:

```
1.2.1Title of the Chapter
```

(There is no space between '1' and 'T')

I want the output as:

```
String 1: 1.2.1
String 2: Title of the chapter
```

I tried this:

```
strParagraphs = 1.2.1Title of the chapter;
string[] lines1 = Regex.Split(strParagraphs, "(\\d{1}).(\\d{1}).(\\d{1})");
also
string[] lines1 = Regex.Split(strParagraphs, "^\\w+");
```

I could not arrive at my desired output. Can someone please suggest, where is it that I am going wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: You could try something like `Regex.Replace(input, @"^([\d.]+)", "$1 ")` (or `Regex.Split(input, @"^([\d.]+)")`), but how do you tell if the digit belongs to the text, and not the bullet point?

Comment: Ok, In that case, I must a space between, "1" and "T" as you mentioned and then look to split the string

Comment: Instead of Regex.Split which is good with seperators, I would use Regex.Match. For example :   

    var strGroups = Regex.Match(inputstring, @"(\w+\.\w+\.\d+)(.*)").Groups;
    string[] strArray = new[] { strGroups[1].Value, strGroups[2].Value };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work like a charm:

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(inputstring, @"(\d+.\d+.\d+)");
```

Result:

```
1.2.1 
Title of the Chapter
```

Note: the result may differ depending on .net version!

For further information, please see:
[Regex.Split Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I does work like a charm!!
Thank you so much!!!
Just a short and greedy question:
what if the leading digits have a format like this - 1.2A.1 or 1.2.1A??

Comment: Well, you need to change the pattern to: `@"(\d+.\d+..\d+)"` In case of multiple patterns, you can write it this way: `@"(pattern1)|(pattern2)|(pattern3)"`

Comment: Maciej Los! Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: Unescaped `.` in regex matches any character (but a newline without `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier).

Comment: @MaciejLos 
The above line [code] Regex.Split(inputstring, @"(\d+.\d+.\d+)");

also fetches items like 1.2.11Subtitle. How do I restrict it for fetching only 1.2.1Title??

Comment: @Sharma, remove `+` after last `d` to get only one digit ;) But i need to warn you... This should return: `1.2.1` and `1Subtitle`